# "Class not found" when trying to create inheritance between entities under zf2 / doctrine

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have a set of entities with Doctrine 2 annotations in a project under Zend Framework 2.
When i try to generate the schema using :

```
php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --force
```

or when i try to generate the getters/setters using :

```
php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:generate-entities --update-entities="true" --generate-methods="true" module/Application/src
```

I allways get this error :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Application\Model\Entity\Capteur' not found in /home/...MyApp/module/Application/src/Application/Model/Entity/CapteurResident.php on line 9
```

Here the complete stack :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Application\Model\Entity\Capteur' not found in /home/...MyApp/module/Application/src/Application/Model/Entity/CapteurResident.php on line 9
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/...MyApp/vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine:0
PHP   2. include() /home/...MyApp/vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine:4
PHP   3. Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner::run() /home/...MyApp/vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine.php:59
PHP   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /home/...MyApp/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Console/ConsoleRunner.php:64
PHP   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() /home/...MyApp/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126
PHP   6. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() /home/...MyApp/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:195
PHP   7. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() /home/...MyApp/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:874
PHP   8. Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\SchemaTool\AbstractCommand->execute() /home/...MyApp/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:257
PHP   9. Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getAllMetadata() /home/...MyApp/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Console/Command/SchemaTool/AbstractCommand.php:59
PHP  10. Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver->getAllClassNames() /home/...MyApp/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:113
PHP  11. require_once() /home/...MyApp/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/AnnotationDriver.php:237
```

CapteurResident and CapteurEmbarque are two entities that extends Capteur exactly the same way.

```
<?php
namespace Application\Model\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class CapteurResident extends \Application\Model\Entity\Capteur
{

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class CapteurEmbarque extends \Application\Model\Entity\Capteur
{
```

If i remove the entity 'CapteurResident', everything works fine !

```
Entity classes generated to "/home/...MyApp/module/Application/src".
```

But not on the development server: on this one, I have the error on another inheritance relationship ... although everything is the same except for the database parameters.
I really do not understand why this bug occurs differently on one machine and on the other and why some inheritances work and others do not.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Application\Model\Entity\Mesure' not found in /home/.../module/Application/src/Application/Model/Entity/MesureCapteurEmbarque.php on line 9
```

Here the Capteur Class :

```
<?php
namespace Application\Model\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 */
class Capteur
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
```

The cli-config.php :

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner;
require_once 'bootstrap.php';

$entityManager =GetEntityManager ();

return ConsoleRunner::createHelperSet ( $entityManager );
```

The bootstrap.php (i do nothing special except adding mysql enums):

```
<?php
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

function GetEntityManager() {
    $paths = array (
            'module/Application/src' 
    );
    $isDevMode = true;

    // the connection configuration
    $localConfig = include __DIR__ . '/autoload/local.php';
    $dbParams = $localConfig ['doctrine'] ['connection'] ['orm_default'] ['params'];

    $config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration ( $paths, $isDevMode, "data/proxies", null, false );
    $entityManager = EntityManager::create ( $dbParams, $config );
    $platform = $entityManager->getConnection ()->getDatabasePlatform ();
    $platform->registerDoctrineTypeMapping ( 'enum', 'string' );
    return $entityManager;
}
```

Comment: Didn't you forgot to use  InheritanceType, DiscriminatorColumn and DiscriminatorMap annotations? Some dudes run into same problem http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-615

Answer (score 1):

Thank you. I finally found a solution : to force the behavior of Zend autoloader. But I still find it weird to have to do that.

I added these lines at the beginning of bootstrap.php :

```
<?php
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

//insert
Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory::factory ( array (
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array (
                Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader::LOAD_NS => array (
                        "Application" => __DIR__ . "/../module/Application/src/Application" 
                ) 
        ) 
) );
```

Comment: I had this problem with my Entity dependencies.  Thanks for providing an easy solution.